# Load an external web page in cordova page in Android

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

How to load an external webpage in cordova page (register.html). I used to know the `window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com', '_self')` using the inappbrowser plugin. But when i use this command, my phone's hardware backbutton will not work. It cannot go to the previous cordova page when i click my hardware backbutton. I have to restart my app for further actions.

Comment: Can you list the platform(s) you are developing for? Also what do you mean by back button doesnt work. It doesn't go back in history?

Comment: i have updated my question. im working with android platform only

Answer (score 0):

Use _blank parameter instead of _self, as self overwrites all your app content and cordova stops working

```
window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com', '_blank');
```

without location bar:

```
window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com', '_blank', 'location=no');
```

Comment: it look like an old browser. I have to make a custom browser view. Howz it possible ?

Comment: You can remove the location bar, see my edited answer. But if you still don't like it, you can create your own plugin that uses a native webview, that will require some work and android native development knowledge